# How to create replica set of mongodb in ubuntu and enable it?

Tags: javascript, linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I am using MongoDB community edition in Ubuntu  22.04. How can I make replica set in my local machine and how can I enable it to use in my node js application?

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/